# Why do we use `f` for float datatypes but not for byte and short?

Tags: java, types

If we use `float` data type in Java we have to add `f` at the end of floating point literal as Java assumes it to be `double` data type and gives an error why not do the same for `short` and `byte` as both have lower ranges than `int`.

Comment: Because it doesn't really matter for common values for `short` and `byte`. But for precision, `float` differs from `double`.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102955/java-why-do-you-need-to-specify-a-f-in-a-float-literal

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have this thing with a `byte` for example because a `byte` can always be treated the same. It is allways a byte. But real numbers can only be represented as approximations. The difference between `double` and `float` is that `double` uses 64 bits and `float` 32. I.e. float is of less percision. 
It is a similar thing to the `int` and `long` for integers. The default type for integers is `int`. Similarly the default type for real numbers is `double`.

Now if you want to use a `float` precision instead. You need to somehow let the compiler know. 
That is precisely why the `f` is there. To tell the compiler how to treat the value.

Basically, when you do this `float x = 0.1f` you implicitly cast the `0.1` literal to a float. 
This statement is equal to `float x = (float) 0.1`

Now lets try something:

```
float x = 0.1f;
double y = 0.1;
```

`System.out.println(x == y)` will give you `false`. Why? Lets see the first 20 digits after the decimal point:

```
0.1f --> 1000000014901161200
0.1  --> 1000000000000000055
```

I hope this helps.