# Java- Why the method argument treats the float value as double value?

Tags: java, casting

I've defined a method with one parameter of type float shown below:

```
public float getValue(float value){

    return value;
}
```

When I call this method by passing float value say **10.1201** shown below:

```
float value =  methodReturnTest.getValue(10.1201);
```

My IDE says to cast the argument to float. I tried searching but couldn't get the appropriate answer. so posting it.
Please explain .

Thanks.

Comment: pass value as ..10.1201f..i.e. 'f' at the end..by default it takes as double

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748160/why-f-is-placed-after-float-values

Comment: I believe this comes down to how the compiler treats numbers.  In this case you could use `10.1201f` instead, which tells the compiler to treat the value as a `float` instead of a `double`

Answer (score 11):

Java takes `10.1201`  as `double`.  In order to pass a `float` value you should append `f` to it like this:

```
float value =  methodReturnTest.getValue(10.1201f);
```

Comment: or else you could cast like
getValue((float) 12.36565);

Answer (score 4):

In java [Float Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) are specify by using f at the end  otherwise it be treated as double literal.

Do like this

```
float value =  methodReturnTest.getValue(10.1201f);
```

Answer (score 3):

Float is single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point and
Double is double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point.
When you use a value with decimal points and if you don`t specify is as 0.23f (specifically float) java identifies it as a double.

For decimal values, double data type is generally the default choice taken by java.
[check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `f` after a float number. If you doesn't, Java won't know if the number is supposed to be treated as a float or as a double.

```
float value =  methodReturnTest.getValue(10.1201f);
```