# Format method of String

Tags: java, string

When I am writing this code

```
float f=56.7876f;
System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f",f));
```

the output is: `56.787601470947`

but, when I am writing this code

```
System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f",56.7876));
```

the output is: `56.787600000000`

Why in both the cases different outputs are being printed despite of the fact that the functionality of both the code is same?

Comment: `56.7876` without the `f` suffix is a `double` value.

Comment: Try `56.7876f`...

Comment: I want to know why in 56.7876f when i am using specific format it is printing 56.787601470947. Why it is not appending the given number with zeroes as in second case when i am using 56.7876

Comment: @Ankit, kindly let me know if my solution helps. I would appreciate if you could upvote and mark accepted the solution you found helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [why f is placed after float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748160/why-f-is-placed-after-float-values) now consider this,

```
    float f = 56.7876f;
    System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f", f));        //                 56.787601470947
    System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f", 56.7876));  //                 56.787600000000
    System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f", 56.7876f)); //                 56.787601470947
```

For floating point literals the default type is `double`. When you say, `f = 56.7876`, the compiler will give warning `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float`. You would need to explicitly type cast it to float (considering the loss of precision from double to float).

In this example the output printed from *56.7876* is of type *double* *56.787600000000* while the rest are of type *float*.

To give you a better example, conider the following scenario.

```
    float f = 56.7874f;
    System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f", f));        //                 56.787399291992
    System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f", 56.7874));  //                 56.787400000000
    System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f", 56.7874f)); //                 56.787399291992
```

This clearly indicates a loss of precision from `56.7874` to `56.7873`

Comment: so why is 0 coming in case of double and random numbers in case of float??

Comment: Good question. I would say I am not 100% sure on this, but as per my knowledge, the default datatype for storing floating point numbers in memory if type double. The trailing 0's just indicate the precision that double has being a 64-bit double literal while float is 32-bit float literal.

Comment: Say when we add two numbers we just consider the first two floating point values and discard the rest. Float somehow seems to consider the precise values of calculation while saving in memory.

Comment: @Ankit, I would appreciate if you upvote and mark the answer you found helpful :) Thank you.

Comment: Yes i will upvote  answers and i usually do to those answers which clear my doubt. So far nobody is able to tell why random numbers are coming in after decimal case of floating numbers and 0's in case of double values.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f",56.7876)); it is returns 12 char fractional part filling with 0 and it consider 56.7876 as double.

you can refer following link:-
https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples